# Create a temporary html-file in a link/js-funcion

Tags: javascript, html

Do you know how I can use a link that calls a js function or sth to create an html file defined by the link.

I want to display a plain text, whenever the user clicks on my link.

I figured alert won't suit me and I don't want to have it as an external document.

Do you know if this is possible?

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few options really.

You say create html file, but also mention plain text. So, I'm going to write about HTML (although plain text will work in the same manner)

Have a blank HTML page for this, and when you open it, you pass through the HTML as a string, possibly in a cookie or similar (depends on how big the HTML string is).

Or, store the new HTML in the DO<(use Fragments or similar) or a string, and then use something like the jquery Overlay() to simulate a new page. Within the overlay, you simply append the desired fragment to an existing DIV

Lastly, check out things like [toastmessage](http://akquinet.github.io/jquery-toastmessage-plugin/) (js plugin) as it may help you - it's simlar to an alert but more functionality. I often use toastmessag and [blockui](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/) together.

Comment: Wow...toast looks great! :D
I'll see, if I can use it - I want to do a legal informatin that the user has to accept and it would be really cool, if that thing could just fade in, wait for the user to click accept and the disapear.
I'm gonna have a lot of fun with this - thx